# ToString changes Javascript Object to Undefined

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, tostring

```
mysqlconnection.query("SELECT userID FROM users_session WHERE userSessionID = '" + SESSION_ID_ESCAPED + "'", function SelectCb (err, rows) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
else {
    console.log(rows[0]);
}
```

How do I turn `row[0]` into a `string` so that the browser can view it?

The console tells me `rows[0] = {userID: 2}` // This is `[object Object]` in any sort of transfer.

I used ,    `var TheID = rows[0].toString //` TheID is now undefined when console.log'd or sent out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`Object.prototype.toString\` always return \`\[object \*\]\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151809/why-does-object-prototype-tostring-always-return-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
var TheID = rows[0]['userID'].toString();
```

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `rows[0]['userID'].toString();`?  Or equivalently, `rows[0].userID.toString();`.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
console.log(rows[0].userID);
```

you will get the userID.