# Javascript error messages, custom object representation

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to make the runtime use a different object representation in the error messages.

A typical error message

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toggle'`

It would be helpful if we can give a better representation to the object than `[object Object]` .In other languages you can make it print a better representation of the object by overriding `toString()`.

However it looks like overriding toString has no effect in this case.

Comment: Do all the browsers do that or only IE? In Firefox and Chrome I usually get pretty good error messages. The line should be there so you can `console.log(theObject);` just before the error.

Comment: I copied the error message from chrome actually.

Comment: Yes, that is not a very helpful message. Chrome can break on error and you'll be on the line that caused the error. Press F12, Sources tab, button in the bottom that looks like a stop sign with a pause icon in it. You can click it multiple times to: not pause at all on errors, pause on uncaught errors and all errors.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and [throw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) your own error messages:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'obj',
  fn: function () {
    return 'hallo';
  }
}


function hasMethod(obj, fn) {
    try {
        if (!obj[fn]) {
            var err = obj.name + ' does not have a method ' + fn;
            throw new Error(err)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

hasMethod(obj, 'moose'); // obj does not have a method moose
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/s86VV/2/)

Comment: yes. throwing my own error messages is one way. I was looking for a solution without try/catches, So it works for error messages thrown anywhere in the code, ones I do not expect too

Comment: This is the only solution I can think of. Otherwise we need a way to modify the `Error` class itself.

Answer (score 1):

The message is browser dependent.  Without making any changes other than switching to chrome you get a nicer message that reports the type of object you were using.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the `Object.prototype.toString` method, which is what would seem to be responsible for creating the `[object Object]` notation you see in those TypeErrors.  Though you can override the `toString` prototype for the `Object` global, the overridden prototype is not what ends up getting called by the native code in TypeErrors and the like.

[Here's a bit more explanation for why that specific notation was chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13152949/2119660) and here's [why it can't be overridden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13171804/2119660).  Effectively, that error message format is more a part of the Javascript compiler and/or implementation than a part of Javascript itself!

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to convert plain javascript object to string then

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

works absolutely great. Documentation for it is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

But I see "toggle" in the error message you mentioned, I am assuming it is general [JQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which is performed on DOM objects. In this case JSON.stringify() does not work.

To Convert DOM object to string follow [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356258/how-do-i-convert-a-org-w3c-dom-document-object-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can also try `Object.toSource()` (i guess it works only in firefox)

Answer (score -3):

Something like this should work:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function() {
  return '(OBJECT: ' + this.name + ')';
};

foo = { name: 'foo' };
bar = { name: 'bar' };
baz = {}

foo.thing(); // TypeError: Object (OBJECT: foo) has no method 'thing'
bar.thing(); // TypeError: Object (OBJECT: bar) has no method 'thing'
baz.thing(); // TypeError: Object (OBJECT: undefined) has no method 'thing'
```

(node js)

Comment: Doenst work .http://i.stack.imgur.com/c5QeV.png........http://jsbin.com/unonEfI/2/edit